# list of all available MinGW packages

Tags: mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

Following [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/repology/repology-updater/issues/658#issuecomment-599682457), I was wondering if there is a place where one can fetch a list of all MinGW packages. Basically I'm looking for the repository/ies where `mingw-get` tool downloads the packages from. Looking at the internet [this page](http://www.mingw.org/PackageIdentificationHOWTO) explains the naming scheme of the packages and explains that there is a parser to interpret the package names. Also, [this page](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/mingw-get-list-what-is-installed-td29994.html) explains that the list of all installed packages should be at stored at

```
$MINGW_ROOT/var/lib/mingw-get/data
```

in some XML format but not all as far as I understand. Also [here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages) I can see the list of MSYS2-MinGW-W64 packages, but not sure if this is the place were `mingw-get` downloads the packages from.
The final goal is to add the repository/ies to the Repology's [list of repositories](https://repology.org/repositories/statistics) and check how the packages are compared to other repositories.

**P.S.** I think I have found something.[This catalog folder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/catalogue/) on the MinGW SourceForge repository, contains a lot of XML files compressed in LZMA format. The `package-list.xml` points to three other XMLs `mingw32-package-list.xml`, `mingw32-contrib-package-list.xml`, and `msys-package-list.xml`. Consequently, they each point to the other XMLs for each individual package and their dependencies... I think that should be it.